# Bitrix? фильтрация catalog.section

Tags: битрикс, google-maps

у элемента каталога есть свойство привязка к карте google. В настройках элемента пользователь указывает где находится товар используя карту.

Вопрос как сделать фильтрацию в инфоблоке по параметру карты. В arResult у свойства карты есть параметр VALUE в котором хранятся координаты, например

```
"VALUE" => 55.755826,37.6173
```

При использовании arrFilter с параметрами

```
["PROPERTY_MESTO_VALUE"]="55.755826,37.6173";
```

Не находит ничего, может нужно как то по другому сделать этот запрос. Гугл не помог

```
global $arrFilter;
$props = array();

$props["PROPERTY_MESTO_VALUE"]="55.747984908778,37.619247436523";
$arrFilter[]=$props;

$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.section", 
    "ajax-search", 
    array(
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
        "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/cart/index.php",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "USE_FILTER" => "Y",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "23",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
        "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
        "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
        "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
        "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",
        "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
            0 => "GRFIK",
            1 => "GSM",
            2 => "MIN_SMEN",
            3 => "OHRANA",
            4 => "PEREVOZKA_PAY",
            5 => "PITANIE",
            6 => "PROZHIVANIE",
        ),
        "OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "CODE",
            1 => "XML_ID",
            2 => "NAME",
            3 => "PREVIEW_TEXT",
            4 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            5 => "",
        ),
        "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "5",
        "OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "GRFIK",
            1 => "GSM",
            2 => "MIN_SMEN",
            3 => "MIN_CHASOV_V_SMENU",
            4 => "OPERATOR",
            5 => "OHRANA",
            6 => "PEREVOZKA_PAY",
            7 => "PITANIE",
            8 => "PROZHIVANIE",
            9 => "PEREVOZKA",
            10 => "MESTO",
            11 => "",
        ),
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "30",
        "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BASE",
        ),
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "N",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
            0 => "BRAND",
            1 => "RESERV_DATES",
            2 => "AVALIDBE_DATES",
            3 => "OPERATORS",
            4 => "PEREVOZKA",
            5 => "RIHLITEL",
            6 => "TIP_BULDOZER",
            7 => "TIP_OTVALA",
        ),
        "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
        "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "",
        "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "N",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BRAND",
            1 => "RABOCHAYA_SHIRINA",
            2 => "MESTO",
            3 => "PEREVOZKA",
            4 => "RIHLITEL",
            5 => "TIP_BULDOZER",
            6 => "TIP_OTVALA",
            7 => "MASSA",
            8 => "",
        ),
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_ID" => $_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "SECTION_URL" => "",
        "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "SEF_MODE" => "N",
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
        "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
        "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N",
        "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "ajax-search",
        "CUSTOM_FILTER" => "{\"CLASS_ID\":\"CondGroup\",\"DATA\":{\"All\":\"OR\",\"True\":\"True\"},\"CHILDREN\":[]}",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
        "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
        "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнить"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

> После изменения в arrFilter

```
Array
(
    [PROPERTY_MESTO] => 55.74566603524847,37.6171875
)
```

> не находит, а если запрос выглядит так

```
 Array
 (
        [PROPERTY_MESTO] => 55,37
 )
```

> то находит

Есть какие то ограничения по длине? или в чем проблема? не могу понять

```
[MESTO] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 120
            [IBLOCK_ID] => 23
            [NAME] => Местоположение
            [ACTIVE] => Y
            [SORT] => 600
            [CODE] => MESTO
            [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S
            [ROW_COUNT] => 1
            [COL_COUNT] => 30
            [LIST_TYPE] => L
            [MULTIPLE] => N
            [XML_ID] => 
            [FILE_TYPE] => 
            [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5
            [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
            [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
            [SEARCHABLE] => N
            [FILTRABLE] => N
            [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
            [VERSION] => 2
            [USER_TYPE] => map_google
            [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => Array
                (
                    [API_KEY] => (ключ карты)
                )

            [HINT] => 
            [~NAME] => Местоположение
            [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            [VALUE_ENUM] => 
            [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
            [VALUE_SORT] => 
            [VALUE] => 55.755826,37.6173 
            [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 1157:120
            [DESCRIPTION] => 
            [~VALUE] => 55.755826,37.6173 
            [~DESCRIPTION] => 
        )
```

Comment: GLOBAL $arrFilter; задан

Comment: приведите участок кода в котором объявляете $arrFilter и в котором вызываете компонент с переданным в него именем фильтра для фильтрации результата.

Comment: @NikolajSarry привел

Comment: Если это свойство у вас не является типом "список", тогда в массив фильтров нужно передавать `PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE>` без `_VALUE` оно нужно только для типа список. Попробуйте `["PROPERTY_MESTO"]="55.755826,37.6173";`

Comment: @YevhenBondarenko спасибо это помогло, есть теперь проблема если в значении есть "." то фильтр не работает, наверно нужно привести к типу верно ?

Comment: @YevhenBondarenko даже не точка виновата, а кажется проблема в длине значения, есть какие то ограничения ?

Comment: Какой тип данных у этого поля? попробуйте вытащить значение этого свойства у одного из элементов и посмотрите соответствует ли оно фильтру.

Comment: @YevhenBondarenko вот что в массиве при выводе этого элемента, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Разобрался, всем спасибо !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это свойство у вас не является типом "список", тогда в массив фильтров нужно передавать `PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE>` без `_VALUE` оно нужно только для типа список. Попробуйте `["PROPERTY_MESTO"]="55.755826,37.6173";`

- В разделе редактирования компонента значение долготы показывается не то что есть в самом массиве потом. в итоге оно короче